# Converting a hexadecimal array into Binary and then into Decimal

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary, hex, decimal

I have a sample structure which has two sets of data. The first data contains the following Hex array **'00 7F 3F FF 08 FF 60 26'** and then when I convert it into binary and then decimal I get a correct answer which is **'0 127 63 255 8 255 96 38'**.

However, I have some data arrays which are not exactly arranged as the first one, they look something like this **'1 40 0 F 00 40 00 47'** and when I try to convert these kind of data sets the result is inaccurate. I get something like this **'64 0 64 0 71'** while the expected result is **'1 64 0 15 0 64 0 71'**.

This is my code with a sample data:

```
%% Structure


a(1).Id = 118;
a(1).Data = '00 7F 3F FF 08 FF 60 26';

a(2).Id = 108;
a(2).Data = '1 40 0 F 00 40 00 47';



%% Hexadecimal (Data) --> Binary --> Decimal

Data = a(2).Data;         
str = regexp(Data,' ','split');
Ind = cellfun(@length,str);
str = str(Ind==2);

%Hex to Binary 
binary = hexToBinaryVector(str,8,'MSBFirst');

%Binary to Decimal
Decimal = bi2de(binary,'left-msb');
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Why the intermediate conversion to binary?

Comment: well, you are getting 64 0 64 0 71 because you are doing `str = str(Ind==2)` so only length = 2 strings are inputted in to hexToBinaryVector. 2 things you can consider, try what happens when you pass 1 digit into hexToBinaryVector and see if works or add a 0 to the left of str(Ind == 1)

Comment: @Adriaan : I need the binary data for further analysis

Comment: @GameOfThrows: Thank you for the input, however, I tried doing what you had suggested but it gives the following error 'Matrix dimensions must agree.'

Comment: @Sagar even so, you might want to consider transforming `hexToDec` and `hexToBinary` both on the original data, as fewer conversions makes for less room for errors to creep in (both programmatic and numerical)

Comment: huh? what did you try? Add `str(Ind==1)  = strcat('0',str(Ind==1) )` before your str=str(Ind==2) and tell me what you get

Comment: @GameOfThrows:Sorry, my bad! It works!!! :) Thank you so much!! Could you please explain to me briefly what was the meaning of the line str(Ind==1) = strcat('0',str(Ind==1) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding 2 lines should do the trick:

```
 str = regexp(Data,' ','split');
 Ind = cellfun(@length,str);
 str(Ind==1) = strcat('0',str(Ind==1) );
 Ind = cellfun(@length,str);
 str = str(Ind==2);
```

All it is doing is when it sees a String (your Hex) that is 1 Char, it puts a 0 infront of it, so correct it into its correct format. you can actually do this in the cellfun.